# Where is the config with greeting login (upd: pre-login) message in Debian?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, login

I want suppress the message showed up each time on login:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 <ip-addr> tty1
<ip-addr> login:
```

Does someone know where is the config to change it?

**UPD1**

to suppress `<ip-addr>` one can empty the `/etc/hostname` file

still the question, how to suppress the whole greeting message
`motd` things are working for me only within the `SSH` logins, but not for direct server login

Answer (score 6):

Probably you want to change `/etc/motd`, `/etc/motd.tail` or their linked targets. Motd translates to "Message of the day". Also check the contents of `/etc/update-motd.d` (at least on ubuntu). [This](http://wiki.debian.org/motd) is what the Debian Wiki says about it. If you want to remove the motd completely:

```
sudo rm /etc/motd
sudo touch /etc/motd
```

Comment: that one I know, but its only for SSH logins, not for a normal direct login.

Comment: thanx for the link to the debian wiki about the motd, there is described where in the motd `Linux blabla` come from: `uname -snrvm > /var/run/motd`

Comment: Yes, but remember it's overwritten all the time. So if you want to get rid of everything, remove the symlink /etc/motd and replace it with an empty file.

Comment: I created `~/.hushlogin` as described here [link](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/546)

Comment: but the direct login works another way as I see it stays unchanged after all this motd tricks...

Comment: What exactly do you mean with local login? How do you open your shell? Any further commands in .bashrc, that writes stuff?

Comment: local login: direct from the computer, not over the network. thanx guys for the discussion and support, you really helped me to find it out!

Answer (score 3):

So I found it.
It is not a `login` message, it is a `pre-login` or `logon` message described in the files

```
/etc/issue     - normal pre-login
/etc/issue.net - telnet pre-login
```

Here the description:
[link1](http://www.wapopia.com/linux/etcissue.htm)
[link2](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-login-message/)